# Remove page number from abstract

Tags: page-numbering, thesis

This is my `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage]{book}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\input{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\input{abstract}

\end{document}
```

The abstract is:

```
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\chapter*{Abstract}

\endgroup           

\vfill
```

This page, the abstract, is numbered. How can I remove the number from this page?

Comment: The quick solution is to use `\thispagestyle{empty}`. However, you might want *all* the first page of each chapter be so - then it's another question you should ask (or rather look for its solution as it was surely already asked before)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the page number (as well as header and whole footer), you should use the `\thispagestyle{empty}`. Indeed, in the `book` class, new chapter pages are of style `plain`, that means without header yet with page numbering at the bottom.

---

*MWE*

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage]{book}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    Title page goes here
    \cleardoublepage
    %Abstract - begin
        \begingroup
        \let\clearpage\relax
        \let\cleardoublepage\relax
        \let\cleardoublepage\relax
        \chapter*{Abstract}
        \thispagestyle{empty}%<=======
        \endgroup           
        \vfill
    %Abstract - end
\end{document}
```

[image]